# Material UI AutoSuggest with Redux

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autosuggest

I have the below input field below set up with Autocomplete here:
https://material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/
(first react-autosuggest example)

[image]

So when you type 002 these options come up. Though the problem is when you click on one of the options, I get undefined error. Below are settings for the Textfield I have on the page:

```
          value: AccountNumber,
          onChange: this.updateAccountNumber,
          onBlur: this.updateAccountNumber,
```

So somehow when you click, value for this field ends up being undefined

i have a working Autosuggest CodeSandbox set up here with console.logs I added for testing here:https://codesandbox.io/s/m35z5l98ox

As you see as you type it prints one letter less (possibly consolelog kicks in before state update) which is fine but when you select an item from the list, it doesn't trigger an onChange event (which it should since value in the field is changing)... So if you click the field, you will get the full value you selected from the list ( which I don't quite know how that list value gets pasted into the field)...

To clarify: This Account Number field is set up with Redux, so what you type gets saved thru onChange to Redux Store. Once the suggestions gets displayed and you select one from the list, at that moment, value of the input field gets to be undefined and autosuggest fails to put what you clicked on, in the suggest list to inside the field.

I am thinking suggestions is wiping out the field to write down the value I clicked on into the field and failing to do that job, but can't figure why it's failing and how to fix it...

Comment: The onChange triggers just fine in your CodeSandbox. You are confusing yourself with your logging because `setState` is not synchronous. If you log `newValue` within `handleChange` rather than just the state, you'll see that `handleChange` is being triggered exactly as you would want.

Comment: my problem is when you type and select an item from the list my redux thinks field is undefined. I need to create a different codesandbox for redux version it's hard to visualize.